# why my bootstrap template is not working in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I tried to use Bootstrap in Asp.net but layout is not working. please help me why my layout is not working. I don't know I put every Css and Html. my navbar looks ok but not working.
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

[image: Broken Nave bar.]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @*@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")*@
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
     awesome.min.css" />
    <link href="~/Content/MyMainLayOut.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data- 
                toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" 
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPortfolio" 
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Portfolio
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria- 
                         labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column 
                             Portfolio</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column 
                             Portfolio</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column 
                             Portfolio</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column 
                             Portfolio</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio 
                             Item</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data- 
                         toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Blog
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria- 
                        labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPages" data- 
                     toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Other Pages
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria- 
                         labelledby="navbarDropdownPages">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="404.html">404</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Navigate to your linked css and ensure they load in the browser... i.e. http://{yoururl}/Content/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you commented out this line.

```
@*@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")*@
```

If you haven't moved any files around or renamed them, and you've installed bootstrap in your application, that line of code should load your bootstrap files.  You can check /App_Start/BundleConfig.cs to see what files it will load if you uncomment it.

I also don't know what these files contain but they may have some conflicting css.

```
<link href="~/Content/MyMainLayOut.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` and `<html>` has no end tags in U're code .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
.
.
 </head>
 <body>
 **** U're HTML goes here ****
 **</body>
</html>**
```